# How to fit an implicit function into a simple approximate function?

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have a function $f(x0)=\int g(x0,x) dx$. 
When I plot this function vs x0, I find that f(x0) is linear in a certain range of x0, let's say, in the range [x01,x02]. I want to fit this function f to a line (A x0 + B) in the range [x01,x02]. Can anyone please tell how to do this?
When I used FindFit to do this, the error was "first argument is not a rectangular array." Function f(x0) is not an array. Then it means i can't use FindFit function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very simply by making a table (rectangular array) of the values.  Let `fn` be the function that you have created using the integral.  I will use

```
fn[x_?NumericQ] := N[Tanh[x/3]]
```

for the demonstration.  Create the table

```
data = Table[{x, fn[x]}, {x, -1, 1, 1/16.}];
```

Carry out the fit

```
Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```

Giving

> -5.18754*10^-18 + 0.325728 x

Comment: I did exactly the same yesterday and solved the problem.  But still, thanks a lot for the answer!